# git push fails after moving remote repository on same server

Tags: git, git-remote

I've got a git working repo and a bare repo on the same server as follows:

```
/
+---dev
|    +---work
|    |    |   
|    |    +---.git
|    |    +---src
|    |    +---...
|    |
|    +---bare-repo.git
|
+---other
```

Pushing and pulling from the work repo to the bare repo was working fine. Then I had the need to reorganise the directories like this:

```
/
+---dev
|    +---work
|    |    |   
|    |    +---.git
|    |    +---src
|    |    +---...
|
+---git
|    +---bare-repo.git
|
+---other
```

While in `/dev/work` I changed the remote URL with:

```
git remote set-url origin /git/bare-repo.git
```

This command succeeded, but when I trying to `push` I'm getting:

```
fatal: '../bare-repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Interesting. While `git remote -v` shows

```
origin  /git/bare-repo.git (fetch)
origin  /git/bare-repo.git (push)
```

the git config file contains:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
    remote = ../bare-repo.git
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin"]
    url = /git/bare.repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

So, the `set-url` did not change the `remote` for branch master. Should it? I guess, no. So the command I've found to change the URL of the remote 'origin' was not the best. I can edit the config file and correct the path manually, I suppose, but what would have been the correct procedure?

Comment: The `remote` for `master` should be the *literal string* `origin`: `git config branch.master.remote origin`. That way Git can indirect through the name `origin` to whatever the URL is.

Comment: With that configuration bug corrected, `git remote set-url origin` will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. (Not that I have had any doubt :-) Out of curiosity: Any idea what I might have done to get that false entry into the config file?

Comment: I don't know how it got brokenated: solving that mystery would be good. But OK, I'll turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how *this* happened:

> ```
> [branch "master"]
>     remote = ../bare-repo.git
>     merge = refs/heads/master
> ```

but the middle line *should* read:

```
    remote = origin
```

With that fixed, everything else should Just Work.